# Jetty - .cer/.p7b - no suite cipher (No cipher suites in common)

Tags: ssl, jetty-9

I am with little knowledge of certificates.

Need add certificate for jetty (v.9.4.11) which is a part of application.

Try with self-signed - all OK. But now, need do it with organization official certificate.

Administrator gives me 2 files - .cer and .p7b. Documentation of application said that enough command like:

keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias mydomain -file mydomain.crt -keystore keystore.jks

I will try this command with .cer instead .crt. Keystore was created, configured jetty-http.xml and started application. Try open - and error SSL_ERROR_NO_CIPHER_OVERLAP.

Check with openssl connect to my address with -tsl1/1_1/1_2 - nothing, connection ok, but but nothing in keystore.

Check with keytool content of keystore - 1 entry, trustedCertEntry and no key (not private/not public)

Is it real to configure only with this 2 files - .cer/.p7b or i need something else?

Answer (score 0):

Usually when setting up SSL Certificates, you will more often than not have 2 or 3 files.

The base working format for certificates is a certificate / key pair.
For example, you could have a certificate for `example.com` with it's associated key.

```
example.com.cer
example.com.key
```

If the certificates were created using a provider, you will most likely also need the Root Certificate Authority. In our infra for instance, our ROOT CA's are in the `.pem` or `.cer` format. Here is a config for one of my webservers, using the `entrust.crt` as the root ca chain file :

```
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/entrust.crt
```

In your case, you have a .p7b file. P7B files often have more than a single entry, they can contain both the certificate and the ROOT CA's chains. You can open the p7b in a windows machine, then find the certificates and right-click > Export. Export your files in Base64 and set them on your server.

[image: ExportCert]
[image: Base64]

Comment: Try this, but not help :(

Comment: Can you show your configuration? Both the config of the app (where it points to the SSL files) and the contents of your SSL certs directory?

Comment: Technically the chain file is more the list of intermediate certificates, as needed, because the (self signed) root one is in the trust store and is not exchanged during TLS handshake. `.pem` and `.cer` (or `.crt` or `.cert`) are just extension names, and are arbitrary, they exist just to ease humans work. Other than that there is two encoding format (PEM and DER) and various container formats (PKCS#7, PKCS#12)

Comment: @Dexirian when testing a self-signed via openssl gives normal answer, and what can give the certificate in the store, if key is not there, only trustedCertEntry and any request gives essentially the NULL

Comment: @Dexirian at your keystore you have only trustedCertEntry or privateKey too?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that beginner .csr-file was incorrect. 
-Recreated it

- get .cer
- run in cmd: certutil -repairstore my "serial" for generate key
- export to .pfx

-connect apllication to .pfx